# CIFS mounted on Linux from Windows shows corrupt/distorted images

Tags: samba, jpeg, cifs

I have mounted a Windows (NAS) folder onto a Turnkey-Linux server using `cifs-utils`. When viewing some of the images on the Linux side they will visually show distortion/corruption but will be fine on the Windows side.

[**Example 1**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiC7u.png) (Left: Linux, Right: Windows)

[**Example 2**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syxn0.png) (Left: Linux, Right: Windows)

In some cases with Firefox (69.0), the image will not show up at all only displaying a blank border with the file location in the top left. In Chrome (76.0.3809.132) it will display an [extremely corrupt image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWFW4.png).

*Some troubleshooting I have already tried:*

- Re-mounted the folder in both the same and different location. *The same images are always distorted/corrupted*.
- Use a different (backup) Windows NAS.

Has anyone experienced this before and know what causes it?

Comment: What SMB protocol version did you use when mounting, and what client kernel version is running on the Linux client?

Comment: Kernal Version: 4.9.0-8-amd64. Protocol: SMBv3 (Windows Server 2008 R2).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [known bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=900821) with the version of Apache2 (2.4.25 Debian) I am using that serves the CIFS files in a funny manner causing the file corruption. For those using Apache2 you will likely be dealing with the `httpd.conf` file in your `sites-enabled` folder. In my Turnkey Django distro it is a file called `django.conf` within the `sites-enabled` folder but it is essentially the same as `httpd.conf`.

By default, Apache2 uses MMAP however this is broken when using CIFS. When getting the md5sum from a file on the file system you will constantly get a different hash. This is what causes the problem.

To see this for yourself simply get the md5sum using:

`wget http://localhost/file -O -|md5sum`

Run this line multiple times and you will see the md5sum is different each time.

To turn off MMAP in your Apache2 config file:

1. `cd` to `../apache2/sites-enabled/`
2. `nano django.conf` or `httpd.conf`
3. below `ServerName localhost` add `EnableMMAP Off`
4. Then at the bottom of the `.conf` file add a `<directory>` tag pointing to your CIFS folder. Mine lookes something like this: 

   `<Directory "/etc/www/djsys/static/bom/images/part-img/">
   </Directory>`
5. Save the`.conf` file and then restart Apache2 `service apache2 restart`.

MMAP should now be off and your files on your CIFS should no longer be corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Since I found this question while diagnosing a slightly different* (though possibly  related?) issue with corrupted files on a CIFS Windows share, I'll add what I found.

In my case I was writing large files from an Ubuntu 20.04 VM (using `cifs-utils`) to a Windows network share (located on the same machine, shared by the host OS), and many were failing md5sum checks on the Windows side even though the file size matched.

What seems to have worked for me is setting `cache=none` in my CIFS config. After the change, the relevant line looks something like this:

```
[...],cache=none,credentials=/etc/winsharecreds,file_mode=0640,[...]
```

In case anyone wants more information, I found this solution (and a detailed description of the issue) here:
https://forums.sonarr.tv/t/strange-failures-on-cifs-mounts-solution/16741

My file transfers have seemed a little slower after the change (anecdotally), but so far none of them have failed the automated md5sum checks. I have not yet tried changing `rsize` and `wsize` as described in the post, but that may address the transfer speeds.

---

*: The difference with my case is that the question describes an issue *reading* from a Windows share while my issue was *writing* to the mounted share. It is possible that I also had some corrupted files during read operations, but I don't know because I was not performing md5 checks during most retrievals, and media content seemed to display without issues.

My corrupted files occurred with PHP 7.4.16 writing to a directory which was automounted by systemd (using cifs-utils 6.9-1ubuntu0.1).